# Wierd Gap between two adjacent div in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having a trouble in IE with divs. Given below are two images of a set of divs viewed in FF and IE.

[image: Div alignment in FF]

[image: Div alignment in IE]

You can see a white line appearing in the place of border. 
I am creating this divs dynamically.

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 49px" class=ganttview-grid-row-cell sizset="36" sizcache07230265382227504="352">
<br/>
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 11px" class=ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition></DIV>
<br/>
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 11px" class=ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition></DIV>
<br/>
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 11px" class=ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition></DIV>
<br/>
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 11px" class="ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition last"></DIV><br/></DIV>
```

Given above is the dynamically generated code for the divs.
The classes defined for the div are given below:

```
div.ganttview-grid-row-cell {
float: left;

/* IE problem */
position:relative;

/*top: 0;
left: 0;*/
z-index:0;
```

}

```
div.ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition {
border-right : 1px dotted #6B6659; 
font-size: 150%;
color: black;
height: 21px;
line-height: 120%; 
float : left;
```

}

```
div.ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition.last {
border-right: none;
margin-right: 0px;
```

}

I am having this gap in all the IE versions. Dont know where i am going wrong.
I did find other questions related to this and tried all but its not working. For e.g

1) adding

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

in head tag.

2) setting position to absolute

3) setting margin padding everything to zero.

Adding some more points after some testing. As said earlier these are dynamically created divs, given below is the code in jquery of how it is created.

```
for(var z = 1 ; z <= 4 ; z++ ) {                                                                        
                $i5MinPartition = jQuery("<div>", 
                        {   
                    "class": "ganttview-grid-row-cell-partition",
                    "css": { "width": ((cellWidth/4) - 1) + "px", "text-align": "center"} 
                        });
                if(bgData[count] && bgData[count].workloadValue >= j) {
                    $i5MinPartition.css({"background": "#669900"});
                }
                if(bgData[count] && bgData[count].scheduleAllocationValue >= j) {
                    $i5MinPartition.text('x');
                }                       
                cellDiv.append($i5MinPartition);

                count++;
            }
```

The cellWidth here is 50. Now i found that IE is not taking decimal values for width whereas firefox is taking it.

The equation

> (cellWidth/4) - 1

gives 11.5 in FF whereas in IE it is 11.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tryed to see with the DOM viewer of Firebug where the problem might be ?

Comment: This is actually a TABLE, so why not use <table>?

Comment: No. this is not a table...its a part of bar graph..i just took a print of the available view of the graph.

firefox is not showing any probs. so cant identify the error in Firebug

Comment: I agree with @Diodeus - this is most definitely tabular data and therefore should be represented semantically correct in a <table>

Answer (score 0):

Hi try adding this to the parent element.

```
font-size: 0
```